# Getting "could not load file or assembly 'xsp2'" with Mono 2.10.8

Tags: mono, xsp2, xsp4

I copied these files to C:\MonoWebServer.

xsp2.exe
xsp2.exe.mdb
Mono.WebServer2.dll
Mono.Security.dll

I registered Mono.WebServer2.dll & Mono.Security.dll in the GAC.
When I go to run xsp2.exe I get.
[image]

What am I doing wrong!

Windows 7 - 64bit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok I'v got it working now. Here are the steps.

1. Create an empty Asp.net MVC site.
2. Copy **xsp4.exe**, **Mono.Security.dll** & **Mono.WebServer2.dll** to the root of the site.
   The file structure should look like this.
   **WebSite**
   --bin
   --Content
   --Models
   --Views
   xsp4.exe
   Mono.Security.dll
   Mono.WebServer2.dll
3. Copy those same 3 files into the **bin** folder.
4. Now run xsp4.exe from the root folder. By default it should run on port 8080. So open a browser to http://localhost:8080 and it should work.

**Notes**
I'm not really sure why but xsp creates a new instance of MonoWebServer based on the assembly name of the Server class. So when it trys to resolve it, it defaults to looking in the **bin** folder. Thats why you have to copy xsp and any dependency files to the **bin** folder.

You can get the files **xsp2.exe**, **xsp4.exe**, **Mono.Security.dll** & **Mono.WebServer2.dll** from installing the newest version of [Mono](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html).

**Framework versions**
This works for web sites built on .NET 4.0. If your trying to deploy .NET 2.0 sites then you will need to register **Mono.Security.dll** & **Mono.WebServer2.dll** in the GAC and use **xsp2.exe** instead of **xsp4.exe**.

**Deployment**
Xsp web server does not need the Mono framework to run on Windows machines with .NET Framework installed.

Comment: have you tried running Mono 3.x instead? maybe you don't need so much hackery

Comment: Mono 3.x is in beta right now and wasn't out when I was doing this.

Comment: Cassini also does this in Windows, so it's likely just how it works.