# What is needed to run XSP as a standalone server on Windows?

Tags: c#, xsp

I'm trying to setup a minimal copy of XSP for Windows for students to use in an ASP.NET intro course. They have Visual C#, and I don't want to confuse matters by giving them Mono per se. I don't want to use IIS for various reasons. I did a similar thing previously for JSP with a zipped copy of Jetty, which worked splendidly.

As an experiment I've installed Mono 2.10.9, and can successfully run XSP directly from the installation. However, the executable (xsp2.exe) is in lib\mono\2.0\winhack, and the server environment is in lib\xsp\test. I want to create a directory containing a minimal set of files (xsp2.exe, xsp.exe.config, Mono.WebServer2.dll, and whatever else is needed) which I can zip up and give to the students. However, all I get is a "File Not Found" exception for Mono.WebServer2.

I copied Mono.WebServer2.dll across, and then got the same for Mono.Security. When I copied Mono.Security.dll, the error refers to Mono.WebServer2 "or one of its dependencies" (without telling me which one).

Can anyone tell me what I need as a minimal setup please?

Comment: Why default one that come with VS does not work for you?

Comment: Which default one that comes with VS? If you're talking about IIS, last time I used it I found it was tricky to configure. I want something the students can unzip onto a memory stick and just run, no fuss, same way as I did with Jetty.

Comment: I mean [Visual Studio Development Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx#bkmk_visualstudiodevelopmentserver)

Comment: Can I run that off a memory stick as I wanted? Also will it run on anything except Windows?

Comment: Meanwhile I found a sensible answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/9929622/1231](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9929622/1231)

Comment: So feel free to close the question than. I don't think VS dev server will run on anything but Windows... Side note: if you assume that your students will be able to configure non-default a web server and learn how to debug in it you may as well just let them pick whatever they want as there should be no problems using any of existing once (IIS/IIS Express/VS Dev server/XSP...)