# how to run mono xsp4 (or any exe) as service on windows

Tags: asp.net, windows, service, mono, xsp

based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747169/getting-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-xsp2-with-mono-2-10-8) I was able to start xsp (web server from mono) as standalone webserver to serve some aspx sites.
It is said that xsp depends on some dlls that are stored for this purpose at the \bin directory. If someone try to run xsp without those dlls an error is thrown.

What I am trying to do is run this approach as service on windows in order to start it automatically without the need of log in to the computer. I know that services execute in a separate session, and when I try to execute xsp inside a service, I am having the same error as if I was trying to execute it without the dlls.

That gave me the idea that the service is not finding those dlls and, I may be wrong but, I think that if I could "register" those dlls inside the scope of the service, xsp (or any dll dependant .exe) could in fact execute without trouble inside a windows service.

The errors, both, the one inside the service execution and the one trying to run without dlls is as follows:

[image: execution error]

What I want to know is: is there a path where I can drop those dlls in order to the service to find them? is there a correct way to achieve this (I may be doing something wrong)?

If someone could help me it would be great.

Comment: why do you need xsp in Windows? what are you trying to solve?

Comment: It is just a requirement, I need to have a standalone webserver that works with .net. I have already tried the iis express approach but I couldn't make it work for external requests. The final target is to have this standalone webserver in order to execute it from a service.

Comment: I recommend you Suave

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Perhaps provide a short description of what it is and a link?? thx in advance

Comment: https://suave.io/